# Error when importing the configuration

Tags: 8, configuration, importing-exporting

We have several sites running with Drupal.
On my local machine I run the test versions of each site in the Docker container to add new features or test new ones.

When switching between pages I do the following.
Shut down the container of page-A.
Change to the directory of page-B, start the container.
Then execute the following commands in the terminal in the container:

```
composer clearcache
composer install
drush sql-drop --yes; 
drush sqlc < page-B_init.sql
drush updb
drush cim
```

When running **drush cim**, the following error message appears:

```
 [error]  Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.
Entity type mismatch on rename.  not equal to configurable_language for existing configuration system.site and staged configuration language.entity.en.
Rename operation for simple configuration. Existing configuration system.site and staged configuration language.entity.en. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 755 of /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php).

In ConfigImportCommands.php line 261:

  The import failed due to the following reasons:
  Entity type mismatch on rename.  not equal to configurable_language for existing configuration system.site and staged configuration language.entity.en.
  Rename operation for simple configuration. Existing configuration system.site and staged configuration language.entity.en.
```

I suspect the problem is with the UUID, which I have in the files:

```
environments/_default/config/sync/system.site.yml
environments/_default/config/sync/language.entity.en.yml
```

adapted.
But I don't know any further.
Does anyone have an idea where the error lies?

Use Drupal 8.9.13

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way, but I had this same issue today. I ended up renaming language.entity.en.yml to include .OLD at the end of the filename for a backup, then I re-ran drush cim. After that it accepted my system.site.yml file. Then I took a look at the language.entity.en.yml file and for some reason it had the exact same UUID as the system.site file. I suspect the import is confused about which file is which because they both had the same UUID.